# LINQ Where query with object list

Tags: c#, list, linq, entity, where-clause

I have a list of objects ListA with property Id and I have to make a query in a table that has a column Id and find the rows that the ids are the same. How exactly can I achieve that with a single query and not a foreach loop of listA?

Thank you for your time

```
foreach(var object in listA)
{
  context.Table.Where(x => x.id == object.Id)....
}
```

Comment: Does this not work for you `data.Where(x => x.Id == someId)` ?

Comment: No, because someId is a property of my list, it should be something like that data.Where(x => x.Id == myList.Id). I can achieve that with a foreach loop and a query for its value but I want to do it in a single call. Thank you

Comment: @golto4 Are you able to supply what you can achieve in a foreach loop, which can make it easier for us to help you?

Comment: Im thinking there must be something wrong with the model to be honest. what @TheGeneral said is the most common query to a table that holds an Id

Comment: You can take all Id's from ListA into a HashSet<T>. Then you can write: data.Where(x=> hashSetObj.Conatins(x.Id));

Comment: `table.rows.Where(row => list.Any(item => item.Id == row["Id"]))`

Comment: I added some brief description on what I'm trying to accomplish in a single call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you want to return all rows from the table that have an ID contained in the list of objects with the same ID. The following will achieve this. I can modify my answer to suit your need. Just let me know if you are looking for something slightly different.

```
void Main()
{
    
    var listA = new List<A> { new A { Id = 1 }, new A { Id = 4 } };
    
    var results = context.Table
        .Where(t => listA.Select(l => l.Id).Contains(t.Id))
}
    
public class A
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```